# Margin-top resolution css

Tags: html, css

I have this link:

http://test.dac-proiect.ro/wp/

I want the object "despre noi" to be moved below ... like in this picture

http://i59.tinypic.com/6i5krr.jpg

This is the CSS code:

```
   #top
{
  background-image:url(img/DESPRE-NOI.png);
  width:400px;
  height:38px;
  margin-left:36%;
}
```

code HTML:

```
<div id="main">                 
              <div id="patrat">
              </div>

              <div id="logo-theme">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
                             <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/LOGO.png'; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" />
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="text-logo">
                    <h1>CABINET AVOCAT CODOBAN</h1>
                    </div>

                  <div id="container">                       
                     <div id="top"></div>
                      <div id="mid" style="display: none;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut           enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est  laborum.</p>
                      </div>
                   </div></div>
```

if applicable "margin-top: 311px;" looks good on 1440x900 resolution...but 1366x768 resolution out of the frame

It`s a theme for Wordpress.

Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to specify margin-top on 768 height.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
#top {
    margin-top: 311px;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024) {
 ------code goes here -------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #top {
 margin-top: 311px;
 background-image:url(img/DESPRE-NOI.png);
 width:400px;
 height:38px;
 margin-left:36%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
#top {
    margin-top: 311px;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
#top {
    margin-top: 2%;
}
}
```

So it should?
I do not work

Answer (score -1):

You should use percentaje instead of pixels to set the width and height, as you do with your margin. To make it responsive theres a simple ecuation that you can follow to get the right percentage.
`percentage = target / context` That means, if your target (the element you are setting the percentage for) is 200px and your context (the paretn element of your element) is 400px then your percentage should be `200 / 400 = 0.5 => 50%`

Comment: I put margin-top: 20% and the same thing happens

Comment: And your `width` and `height`? if those are still in pixels the result would be the same always. Anyways, if none of those works you should use media queries as said before

Comment: I started with media queries with [this css trick post](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)